# Why is the final output "B-D"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, output

Keep in mind this is unfinished, the only question I have is why does the console.log produce this output?

> />B /* This is what I expected */
>
> />B-D /* The second output I expected to be just ">/D" I am conused as to how it is coming up with >/"B-D" */

```
graphArray = ["4","A","B","C","D","A-B","B-D","B-C","C-D"];
pointsArray = [];
linesArray = [];
nodes = graphArray[0];
for (i = 1; i < graphArray.length; i++) {
    if (i <= nodes) {
    pointsArray.push(graphArray[i]);
    }
    if (i > nodes) {
        linesArray.push(graphArray[i]);
    }
}
nextpoint = pointsArray[0];
patt = new RegExp(/-.*/);
patt2 = new RegExp(nextpoint + "-");
for (i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {
    x = 0;
    while (x < linesArray.length) {
        if (linesArray[x].replace(patt,"") === nextpoint) {
            nextpoint = linesArray[x].replace(patt2,"");
            console.log(nextpoint);
        }
        x++;
    }
}
```

Edit: *Smacks forehead* it must be getting too late for me I can't believe I missed that. Thank you for point that out. Solved.

Comment: `patt2` is `/A-/`, so it won't match "B-D" and so won't replace the leading "B-". You have to construct a new regular expression each time you find the next point. I think you'll get much better performance using `substring`, or maybe `split` on the hyphen.

Comment: Isn't it be easier to use `split` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `patt2 = new RegExp(nextpoint + "-");` should be inside the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {
    x = 0;
    while (x < linesArray.length) {

        patt2 = new RegExp(nextpoint + "-");
        if (linesArray[x].replace(patt,"") === nextpoint) {
            nextpoint = linesArray[x].replace(patt2,"");
            console.log(nextpoint);
        }
        x++;
    }
}
```